# Extension gcm notification can't open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

i writting a extention gcm notification for chrome. When i sign in account gmail on chrome, first, i can open extension normal. I close extension appication, i reopen extension application, but application can't show. When i sign out account gmail on chrome, i can close open normal application. i don't know why.

Background.js

```
// Returns a new notification ID used in the notification.
var registerWindowCreated = false;
function getNotificationId() {
var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9007199254740992) + 1;
 return id.toString();
}

 function messageReceived(message) {
 // A message is an object with a data property that
  // consists of key-value pairs.

 // Concatenate all key-value pairs to form a display string.
 var messageString = "";
 for (var key in message.data) {
  if (messageString != "")
  messageString += ", "
  messageString += message.data[key];
//messageString += key + ":" + message.data[key];
 }
 console.log("Message received: " + messageString);

 // Pop up a notification to show the GCM message.
 chrome.notifications.create(getNotificationId(), {
title: 'NETWORK MONITOR',
iconUrl: 'gcm_128.png',
type: 'basic',
message: messageString
 }, function() {
if(registerWindowCreated==false)
{
chrome.app.window.create(
  "index.html",
  {  width: 800,
     height: 600,
     frame: 'chrome'
  },
  function(appWin) {}
);
}
});
}

function firstTimeRegistration() {
chrome.storage.local.get("registered", function(result) {
// If already registered, bail out.
if (result["registered"])
  return;

registerWindowCreated = true;
chrome.app.window.create(
  "index.html",
  {  width: 800,
     height: 600,
     frame: 'chrome'
  },
  function(appWin) {}
);
});
}

// Set up a listener for GCM message event.
chrome.gcm.onMessage.addListener(messageReceived);

// Set up listeners to trigger the first time registration.
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(firstTimeRegistration);
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(firstTimeRegistration);
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(firstTimeRegistration);
```

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Network Monitor",
"description": "Chrome platform app.",
"manifest_version": 2,
"version": "1.0",
"app": {
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
 }
},
"permissions": ["gcm", "storage", "notifications","http://*.longvan.net/","webview"],
"icons": { "128": "gcm_128.png" }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's very hard to understand what you're asking. Seems to be a language problem. Can you try to reformulate?

Comment: i build application extension. First, i open application, it show normal. then, i close application. i reopen application, it don't show gui. i continous click open it, but don't see evrything show.

Comment: It seems like it's supposed to not show GUI if `registered` is set. You don't show what's happening in `index.html`.

Comment: thank you! i fixed success. error at chrome.app.window.create.